# Android sms & missed call contentreceiver not working after i read sms/missed call

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

Hello i want to be notified when the number of unread messages in my mobile phone changes and the number of missed calls changes, as of right now my code looks like this:

```
private ContentObserver unreadSMSCO;
private ContentObserver missedCallCO;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    missedCallCO = new ContentObserver(new Handler()){
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange){
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,Calls.TYPE + " = ? AND " + Calls.NEW + " = ?",new String[] { Integer.toString(Calls.MISSED_TYPE), "1" },Calls.DATE + " DESC ");
            int count = cursor.getCount();
            grid.SetPhoneCallNotification(count);
            cursor.close();
        }
    };

    unreadSMSCO = new ContentObserver(new Handler()){
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange){
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, "read = 0", null, null);

            int count = cursor.getCount();

            grid.SetSMSNotification(count);
            cursor.close();
        }
    };

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), true, unreadSMSCO);
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Calls.CONTENT_URI, true, missedCallCO);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(unreadSMSCO);
    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(missedCallCO);
}
```

And this works perfectly when i receive a new sms but when i click on the notification or go to the message app a read the message and then i go back to this app it doesn't fire the content receiver to notify me that the number of unread messages has changed. The same things appens with missed call, i get notified when someone calls me and i dont's answer but when i go to the call logs so that the nofication goes away the content resolver doesn't get called..

Am i doing something wrong here, do i need to add something so that it works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For missed call info You need to call your "missedCallCO" after few seconds of miss call.

Actually missed calls update in android system after few second of miss call. Use Thread and wait for some second like 5 or 6, and then you will get it for sure.

hope this helps

Comment: I'm using a contentObserver, i dont neet to call anything. The idea is the contentObserver wathches for changes in the contentURI database and as soon as he detects a change he fire the event 'onChange', the code works very well to detect when i receive a new message or when i get a missed call, the problem is when i go check the notification of unread messages or missed calls so that they turn to 0 again, the contentObserver doesn't fire